# Playing a SoundCloud file in IOS app

Tags: ios, soundcloud

Using the quick start guide provided would like to play a SoundCloud track within IOS app.

The code provided to play the stream is here:

```
SCAccount *account = [SCSoundCloud account];

    [SCRequest performMethod:SCRequestMethodGET
                  onResource:[NSURL URLWithString:audioFile]
             usingParameters:nil
                 withAccount:account
      sendingProgressHandler:nil
             responseHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                 NSError *playerError;
                 audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:&playerError];
                 audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;

                 [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
                 [audioPlayer play];
             }];
```

Problem: is there a method to play a SoundCloud file without logging in to your SoundCloud account first? We hope all users consider using SoundCloud - however for usability if would be useful if new users could listen to a number of tracks before.

Comment: have you tried omitting the code responsible for account initialization? do you have particular problem?

Comment: Yes tried setting account:nil , didn't work so assuming you need to be logged in to SoundCloud to play audio.

Comment: Magnus, I know this is late but I have the same problem...did you find a workaround??

Comment: you could flag my answer below as correct, thank you.

Answer (score 14):

For public access with the IOS Soundcloud SDK you will need to add the Soundcloud clientID as a parameter to your request string:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?client_id=%@", publicTrackUrlString, yourSCClientID];
[SCRequest performMethod: SCRequestMethodGET 
              onResource: [NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
         usingParameters: nil 
             withAccount: nil
  sendingProgressHandler: nil 
         responseHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
                      // 
         }];
```

Then it will work for public tracks when the withAccount: parameter is nil.

More elegantly, you can as well pack the "client_id" in a dictionary and use it with usingParameters:

`NSDictionary *params = @{@"client_id": yourSCClientID} ;`

Comment: @sn-gerzonic `NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=1954115647 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1954115647.)` I got this error pls give me solution