# Stream Audio with AVPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I'm trying to play audio from a URL using AVPlayer when a row is selected in a table view but it doesn't play. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *streamingString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.json?client_id=fc886d005e29ba78f046e5474e3fdefb", [streamURLArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSURL *streamingURL = [NSURL URLWithString:streamingString];
    NSLog(@"%@", streamingURL);
    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:streamingURL];
    [player play];
    player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
}
```

An example of streamingURL when I log it is this.

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/146814101/stream.json?client_id=fc886d005e29ba78f046e5474e3fdefb
```

Comment: This may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537080/playing-a-soundcloud-file-in-ios-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

declare AVAudioPlayer globally in your .h file

like this  `AVPlayer *player;`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *streamingString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.json?client_id=fc886d005e29ba78f046e5474e3fdefb", [streamURLArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    NSURL *streamingURL = [NSURL URLWithString:streamingString];
    NSLog(@"%@", streamingURL);
    player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:streamingURL];
    [player play];
    player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
}
```

Comment: this code did not work for me . do you know any alternate way ?

Answer (score 2):

You'll find numerous audio streaming kit all around GitHub.

https://github.com/tumtumtum/StreamingKit

https://github.com/muhku/FreeStreamer

https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer

Answer (score -4):

call this method

```
[player prepareToPlay];
```

before calling

```
[player play];
```

It may help to u.

Comment: He's using an AVPlayer, not an AVAudioPlayer so the "prepareToPlay" method call won't work